# Has the episode count for Black Clover been announced?

Tags: black-clover

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Clover) it's 13 eps, [MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34572/Black_Clover_TV) hasn't said anything and some say it's 50/51 eps.

Does anyone really know how many episodes the series is going to be?

Considering the slow pacing, I think it's going to be longer than 12/13 episodes... but I may be wrong.

Comment: It's time slot, 18:25 on Tuesdays, suggests TV Tokyo wasn't planning it being a year long since most previous shows in that slot aired for three months with a couple being airing for six months.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry probably got updated from the Funimation site, which listed 13 eps.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing "official" has been announced yet, it was assumed that it's going to have 13 episodes because that's kind of the norm nowadays and Funimation did list it at one point as having that many episodes, but they were wrong about episode order before so, who knows.

Recently though, Yonkou_Prod, a fan-site that was responsible for several anime leaks in the past, [claimed that the anime's episode order has been expanded to 51 episodes](https://twitter.com/YonkouProd/status/918330085412716544), and as unlikely as that sounds, they seem confident about their claims...

Whether and who you want to believe is totally up to you, but the fact of the matter is: we don't know anything official yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Wikipedia says 13 episodes, I have a gut feeling it ill be longer.

This is because the third episode was mainly a filler in many ways.

I think if the anime was 12-13 episode season or 24-25 season, there is no way they would have added a filler this early into the series.

So I'm thinking a good 50-60 episode series or it might even be like One Piece and Naruto a long running series.

Comment: Wait that's 2 out of 3 episodes of filler already?

Comment: Yeah but 2nd episodes just elaborated on a cannon past so it technically is  not filler. Just a rearrangement of story from manga.